# При переключении вкладок в вс код (к примеру при переключении с index.html на style.css), появляется такая синяя полоса сверху

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, редактор

была ли у кого такая фигня с вс код?
При переключении вкладок в вс код (к примеру при переключении с index.html на style.css), появляется такая синяя полоса сверху (слева сверху название самого файла). Было ли такое у кого? Работе оно не мешает, но напрягает глаз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая у вас ОС? Если это линукс. есть ли у вас расширения которые меняют интерфейс в общем или топ бар?

Comment: Windows 7x64
.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отключите «Упрощённый стиль» в настройках оформления windows